# Visibility,Name,Price fields missing after configurable product import - magento 2

Tags: configurable-product, magento-2.1.1

After importing configurable products, few of them's visibility, name ,price fields shows empty. Why it is happening, due to this indexing not work successfully and products not displaying on front end
[image]

Comment: Have you added proper data for those records?

Comment: yes,  I just cross checked csv everything is valid and also during validation no errors were shown

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue, and found out that its updating the first simple product.
Simple sku 1001870-0001
Configurable sku 1001870
tested with just the configurable sku in a csv and would change name, import and the simple name changed, configurable still no name. 
Not sure if this will help anyone out. or if anyone has a solution.

Comment: Change your configurable sku to alphanumeric.